Liouville-Arnold and fibration relative to a convex polytope
Liouville-Arnold's theorem indicates that given a Hamiltonian torus action on a manifold and a set of $n$ functions $F$ from the manifold to $\mathbb{R}^n$ defining an integrable system, the pre image of a regular point $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$, namely $F^{-1}(c)$ is diffeomorphic to a $n$-torus if it's compact and connected. Is there any detail that should be taken in account if the image of $F$ is actually a convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Is there any relation with the induced moment map by the Hamiltonian action?

For a symplectic toric manifold, every fiber over a point in the interior of the delzant polytope is diffeomorphic to an $n$-torus. Conversely, every fiber over a point on the boundary of the polytope is diffeomorphic to a torus of lower dimension. You might be interested in applying the Guillemin-Sternberg-Marle local normal form theorem for symplectic toric manifolds.
